# How to debug correctly an Insert statement with PDO (mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, pdo

```
$PDO_db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=UTF-8' , DB_USER, DB_PWD);
$sth = $PDO_db->prepare($insert);   
$arrPar = array(':nome' =>  $nome);         
$r = $sth->execute($arrPar);    
var_dump($arrPar);
print_r($PDO_db->errorInfo());
var_dump($r);
exit();
```

Supppose that the $insert statemet contains a SQL error, with the code above I've noticed the following :

1. Code A

   ```
   print_r($PDO_db->errorInfo());
   ```

   will output anyways:

   ```
   Array (
       [0] => 00000
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
   )
   ```

   but var_dump($s) is false
2. If in the insert statement I have some `placemark` e.g. `:name`

   ```
   "Insert into mytable (name) VALUE(:name);"
   ```

   And then in the `$arrPar = array(':name' => $value)` with `$value=NULL`

   ```
   print_r($PDO_db->errorInfo());
   ```

   will output again:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => 00000
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
   )
   ```

   but var_dump($s) is false

So I'm wondering to know what's the correct way to debug MySQL statements with PDO if the method **errorInfo**, which is supposed to give me a error description, silently quiets errors?

`PDO::errorInfo()` returns an array of error information"

Comment: You need to bind your PDO Statement with the variable.

Comment: I would add `$PDO_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. That should make it a lot more obvious what's going on.

Comment: @GiantofaLannister no he doesn't, his syntax is ok as it is, well as much as he showed from it anyways

Comment: Adding an `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true)` above that will probably give you better hints.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange... are you sure nothing is being iserted? MySQL's return code on success *is* 0, which the `errorInfo` does return. But like @Jack said:

```
try
{
    $PDO_db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=UTF-8' , DB_USER, DB_PWD);
    $PDO_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $PDO_db->prepare($insert);
    echo 'Insert prepared<br/>';
    $arrPar = array(':nome' =>  $nome);//shouldn't this be :name?
    $r = $sth->execute($arrPar);
    echo 'Insert executed<br/>';
    var_dump($r);
}
catch(PDOException $pdoE)
{
    echo $pdoE->getMessage().'<br/>';
    var_dump($pdoE);
}
exit();//?
```

That should give you more clues as to what is going on. Also, you state (twice) that a `var_dump` of `$s` is false, but you're assigning the return value of the execute call to `$r`... I'm assuming that's a typo, but you never know, hence the comment on `':nome'`.
Also take @Clarence's advice to heart, and set your php.ini error reporting to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`, you might hate the vast amount of warnings it issues at first, but it avoids any issues you might (and probably will) encounter when you deploy your code on another machine, or you upgrade your PHP version. Anyway: it's not like PHP is that strict of a language that `E_STRICT` is going to cost you *huuuge* amounts of time to fix the warnings...

Comment: $arrPar = array(':nome' =>  $nome);//shouldn't this be :name?
This was my mistake in the post, the code was correct a that point

Comment: Yea it was supposed to be var_dump($r); // not $s

Comment: @kante: Since you accepted this answer, I suspect/hope you figured out what the problem was, care to share what the issue was or what Exception was thrown that helped you solve this?

Comment: I accepted the answer because, until now it's the best way I saw to capture eventual SQL mistakes wth PDO. On the other hand I think PDO class could have been more "errorCatching oriented" , thinking also to the problem to not to be able to print out for debug purposes the prepared query, with placemark replacement. (not without implementing your own method to perform the task)